# docker compose up works well but docker run does not

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, redis

I was trying to run main server image and redis

So I follow below process

1. `docker network create --bridge backend`
2. `docker run -d --network backend -p 6379:6379 "redis alpine image"`
3. `docker run -d --network backend -p 8080:8080 "main server image"`

And I tried to `POST` to server using postman 
But server return 500
[image]

And when I see the log, it says because it cant connect with redis

[image]

but when using

1. `docker compose up -d redis`
2. `docker compose up -d main`

it works well
[image]

my docker compose yml is below like

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  main:
    image : ${REPO_URL}/${ECR_REPOSITORY}:${IMAGE_TAG}
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - backend

  redis:
    image : redis:alpine
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    networks:
      - backend


networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
```

`docker compose up` and `docker run` work different internally?

Comment: You need to specify a `docker run --name` for each container, and that name will be its DNS name on the shared `docker run --network`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because, when using docker-compose, DNS resolves the name of your services (your services are `main` and `redis` as declared in your docker-compose file). When you enter `redis:6379`, it will automatically resolve to `redis_container_ip_inside_network:6379`.

Notice how you are declaring the service name in the compose file. Where are you declaring it when you're not using compose? Hint: you aren't, and this is why, when you use `docker run`, the container just doesn't know what `redis:6379` means.

Instead of using `redis:6379` as the redis endpoint, you will need to use `redis_container_ip_inside_network:6379`. You can assign the IP yourself so that it is always predictable by using the `--ip` parameter. Make sure the IP can be assigned to your docker network subnet (which you can also specify when creating the network with the `--subnet` parameter).

You can find your container IP addresses inside the network with the `docker network inspect backend` command when your containers are running.

Comment: after adding optione `--name redis` in docker run redis it works well and I think it is consistent as you explain. right?

Comment: Then it means that the docker manage internal dns
Most says it is in /etc/resolv.conf
and when `cat /etc/resolv.conf`
```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search ap-northeast-2.compute.internal
```
I can't know what this mean
What I expect is {host name} {ip address}
like in /etc/hosts
where can I see that dns by docker?